# Conditional format custom formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Have a question on how to do a custom formula in conditional format for the following:

```
A1 = DCC220
B1 = 7.50
C1 = 7.00
D1 = 7.60
```

I want to compare the result in B1 (7.50) to a range, C1 lower, D1 upper, but only if the value in A1 is DCC222. Color green if B1 is in the range of C1 and D1 and red if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

- **custom formula for green: `=COUNTIFS(A1; "DCC220"; B1; ">"&C1 ; B1; "<"&D1)`**
- **and for red: `=OR(COUNTIFS(A1; "DCC220"; B1; "<"&C1); COUNTIFS(A1; "DCC220"; B1; ">"&D1))`**

---

**bonus knowledge:** to include C1 and D1 in the range as well, you can add equal sign like this:

- **custom formula for green: `=COUNTIFS(A1; "DCC220"; B1; ">="&C1 ; B1; "<="&D1)`**

---

## FINAL PRODUCT OF OP'S QUESTION:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**CUSTOM FORMULA FOR GREEN APPLIED IN E1 FOR RANGE E:E**

```
=ArrayFormula(OR(COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$2"), E1, ">="&INDIRECT("Index!$B$2"), E1, "<="&INDIRECT("Index!$C$2")),
                 COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$3"), E1, ">="&INDIRECT("Index!$B$3"), E1, "<="&INDIRECT("Index!$C$3")),
                 COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$4"), E1, ">="&INDIRECT("Index!$B$4"), E1, "<="&INDIRECT("Index!$C$4")),
                 COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$5"), E1, ">="&INDIRECT("Index!$B$5"), E1, "<="&INDIRECT("Index!$C$5")),
                 COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$6"), E1, ">="&INDIRECT("Index!$B$6"), E1, "<="&INDIRECT("Index!$C$6"))))
```

**CUSTOM FORMULA FOR RED APPLIED IN E1 FOR RANGE E:E**

```
=ArrayFormula(OR(OR(COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$2"), E1, "<"&INDIRECT("Index!$B$2")), COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$2"), E1, ">"&INDIRECT("Index!$C$2")),
                 OR(COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$3"), E1, "<"&INDIRECT("Index!$B$3")), COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$3"), E1, ">"&INDIRECT("Index!$C$3")),
                 OR(COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$4"), E1, "<"&INDIRECT("Index!$B$4")), COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$4"), E1, ">"&INDIRECT("Index!$C$4")),
                 OR(COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$5"), E1, "<"&INDIRECT("Index!$B$5")), COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$5"), E1, ">"&INDIRECT("Index!$C$5")),
                 OR(COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$6"), E1, "<"&INDIRECT("Index!$B$6")), COUNTIFS(B1, INDIRECT("Index!$A$6"), E1, ">"&INDIRECT("Index!$C$6")))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added it to the Conditional Format Rules but it did not turn green..any thoughts

Comment: How would we do it if we just put the values in ex >=7.00 and >=7.60. I have conditional statements in my actual document for c1 and d1 that the conditional format rules function does not recognize

Comment: It did not like that either. I've not seen the " around the >= here either..will try to remove

Comment: did not like that either

Comment: did work..thanks everyone!

Comment: Is there anyway to have this copy down an entire spreadsheet so each line will apply respectively? I want to do this for about 1000 lines.

Comment: @user190579 yes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jf79znfNoLHTh_CYLYlialJo9g5FYd0bvs_G8M8dkfs/edit#gid=1287170474

Comment: Thank you very much. what you have done works beautifully.....question: I wanted to expand for the rest of my sku's and was able to expand the green to 16 additional sku's with specs....however, I cannot get the red to expand beyond what you have setup. do you think that formula is limited

Comment: I figured it out..you are a genius...thank you very much!!

Comment: Is working beautifully. have another question if you have the time. so i now have the cell either showing green or red based on the index..I want to post on another spreadsheet the words pass or fail (green, red respectively) do you think thats possible

Comment: @user190579 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers